# Expected argument of type "App\Entity\Personnes", "array" given at property path "professeurs"

Tags: php, symfony-forms, symfony5

I have an exception on my "handlerequest" that tells me "Expected argument of type "App\Entity\Personnes", "array" given at property path "professeurs"."
I've been stuck on it for several days now.

My entity user :

```
#[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Reunion::class, mappedBy: 'professeurs')]
private $reunions;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->evenements = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->participations = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->reunions = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

My meeting entity :

```
#[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Personnes::class, inversedBy: 'reunions')]
private $professeurs;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->professeurs = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->sujets = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

My controller :

```
#[Route('/professeur/reunion/create', name: 'create_reunion')]
public function create_reunion(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em): Response
{
    $reunion = new Reunion;
    $form = $this->createForm(ReunionType::class, $reunion);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
        $reunion->addProfesseur($this->getUser());
        $em->persist($reunion);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->render('reunion/create.html.twig', [
        'formView' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

My form :

```
class ReunionType extends AbstractType{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
{
    $builder
        ->add('dateReunion', DateTimeType::class)
        ->add('objet', TextType::class, [
            'attr' => [
                'placeholder' => 'Objet de la réunion'
            ]
        ])
        ->add('professeurs', CollectionType::class, [
            'label' => "Ajouter des professeurs",
            'entry_type' => ProfType::class,
            'by_reference' => false,
            "allow_add" => true,
            "allow_delete" => true
        ]);
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
{
    // $resolver->setDefaults([
    //     'data_class' => Reunion::class,
    // ]);
}
}
```

And for the 'entry_type' :

```
class ProfType extends AbstractType{

public function __construct(protected PersonnesRepository $pr)
{
}
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
{
    $builder
        ->add('personnes', EntityType::class, [
            'label' => false,
            'class' => Personnes::class,
            'placeholder' => "-- Choisir un professeur --",
            'attr' => [
                'class' => "form-select"
            ],
            'choices' => $this->pr->findByRole('PROF'),
            'choice_label' =>  function (Personnes $personnes) {
                return strtoupper($personnes->getNom()) . " " . $personnes->getPrenom();
            }
        ]);
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
{
    // $resolver->setDefaults([
    //     'data_class' => Personnes::class,
    // ]);
}
}
```

[image: The exception]

Normaly my "professeurs" collection can recieve 1 or more entity.

Comment: If you want, you can clone my repository with https://github.com/Nardel34/ap3.git.
Then you use "composer u"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `MenyToMeny` relationship, use the `EntityType` with the option `multiple=true`

Your `ReunionType` should look like this

```
class ReunionType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('dateReunion', DateTimeType::class)
            ->add('objet', TextType::class, [
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Objet de la réunion'
                ]
            ])
            ->add('professeurs', EntityType::class, [
                'label' => "Ajouter des professeurs",
                'class' => Personnes::class,
                'multiple' => true
            ]);

    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
         $resolver->setDefaults([
             'data_class' => Reunion::class,
         ]);
    }
}
```

Add in Entity `Personnes`

```
 public function __toString(): string
 {
    return  $this->getPrenom() .' '. $this->getNom();
 }
```

In file templates/reunion/create.html.twig remove option `render_rest` from `form_end`

Comment: Thanks for your help, if with this, I can't add simultaneously more that one "personnes" entity in my "professeurs" collection :/

Comment: No, you can. EntityType has a multiple  parameter for this. Look at my example more carefully))